# Run Hamachi and Tightvnc on startup without logging in on raspberry pi

Tags: networking

I have a raspberry pi with hamachi, haguichi and tightvnc installed. I have these 3 setup already, but I'd like to configure to run hamachi and tightvnc on startup withouth the user logging in on the desktop cause i already have setup a login screen for the user to use to login.

Thank You for the help in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this post to get TightVNCServer running](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27676/auto-start-tightvncserver-on-raspberry-pi-2/27677#27677). I would imagine it isn't too different to do the same for Hamachi although I have no experience of it.